# how do you convert to cidr in python3?

Tags: python

I have an ip address 1.2.3.4 with a subnet mask 255.255.255.0

I want to convert this to cidr notation
1.2.3.4/24

How do I do this in Python3?

Comment: from the command line.

Comment: sum([bin(int(x)).count('1') for x in '255.255.255.0'.split('.')])

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: What format what comes in? I assume he just has two strings `'1.2.3.4'` and `'255.255.255.0'`. (I suppose it's _possible_ that he has, say, two 32-bit integers 16909060 and 4294967040, but I'd think he would have mentioned it if so.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html#ipaddress-howto) module in the standard library.

---

An address plus a netmask is either a network or an interface, not an address. Given that you've got some of the host bits set (it's 1.2.3.4, not 1.2.3.0), either you've got an interface, or you've got a non-canonical name for a network; I'll assume it's an interface, so use [`ip_interface`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_interface):

```
>>> i = ipaddress.ip_interface('1.2.3.4/255.255.255.0')
```

Or, if you want to make sure it's explicitly IPv4 not IPv6:

```
>>> i = ipaddress.IPv4Interface('1.2.3.4/255.255.255.0')
```

Or you can compose it out of an address and a network, instead of out of a combined string. It depends on what format you have this information in and what makes sense to you.

---

To get the CIDR format, use the [`with_prefixlen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Interface.with_prefixlen) accessor:

```
>>> i.with_prefixlen
'1.2.3.4/24'
```

---

You can also do all kinds of other nifty things—extract the address (`1.2.3.4`) as `i.address`, or the network (`1.2.3.0/24`) as `i.network`, or enumerate all the addresses on the network by treating `i.network` as a sequence, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IPy](https://github.com/autocracy/python-ipy/) library to do this. If you scroll down to the documentation you can see the string conversions it can do. The one we're after is `strNormal(1)`

```
IP("1.2.3.4/255.255.255.0").strNormal(1)
```